# How to create logoff in C# with ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to create a login system, I have been able to do the registration part and the login part, but I am not able to create the part for the user to leave the session (exit the system).

Note: I have a repository with the SQL commands

Could someone help me with how to do this part?

I am using the Entity Framework and I do it by database first

Here is my controller

```
public class AccountUserController : Controller
{
    private clsContext cnn = new clsContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        clsUserRepository usu = new clsUserRepository(cnn);
        return View(usu.AccountList());
    }

    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(clsAccountUser userObj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            clsUserRepository usu = new clsUserRepository(cnn);
            usu.Register(userObj);
            cnn.SaveChanges();

            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.Message = userObj.usuNome + " " +"Successfully registered!";
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(clsAccountUser userObj)
    {
        cclsUserRepository usu = new clsUserRepository(cnn);

        if (usu.Login(userObj) == 2)
        {
            Session["Logged"] = usu.Login(userObj);

            return RedirectToAction("Logged");
        }
        else if(usu.Login(userObj) == 1)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Invalid username and password";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "RE: " + userObj.usuRe + " Invalid" ;
        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Logged(clsAccountUser usuarioObj)
    {
       if(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Logged"]) != 0)
       {
           return View();
       }
       else 
       {
           return RedirectToAction("Login"); 
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll be much better off using ASP.NET Identity instead

Comment: I need to use the
entity framework. But how can I do this using the ASP.NET Identity instead?

Comment: ASP.NET Identity uses EF for database access. https://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set all session variables to NULL, abandon your session and redirect to homepage to create a Logout functionality.

In your controller, create a new action -

```
Public ActionResult Logout()
{
    Session["LoggedData"] = null;
    Session.Abandon();
    return RedirectToAction("Default", "Home");
}
```

Comment: Do I need to create a view to the Logout?

Comment: If you want a custom message on Logout, you need another view. But, if you want it to redirect to Homepage, this above code works.

Comment: If you create Logout View, then use Return View() instead of Return RedirectToAction().